# Uniqueness of Witten-Dijkgraaf 2D TQFT at 0th dimension

Tags: higher-category-theory, quantum-field-theory, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

If I understand correctly, Dijkgraaf-Witten TQFT in dimension 2 is the
following. Fix any finite group $G$, we define a field over a closed
2-manifold to be a principle $G$ bundle (it's automatically flat since
$G$ has trivial Lie algebra). Fixing an action functional, we get a
number assigned to the closed 2-fold. In this question, I will not
alter the action functional.

To go to codimension 1, we assign the circle the space of functions
over the space of fields, i.e.

$$Z_G(S^1) = \mbox{Function}(\{G\mbox{-bundles over
circle}\}),\mathbb{C})$$

So any 2-fold with boundary being a circle is just a function in
$Z_G(S^1)$ in the natural way. So far, it gives a $(2,1)$ TQFT, and it
is natural to me.

And then we attempt to go to codimension 2 (i.e. dimension 0). By
assigning the category of representations of $G$ to the positively
oriented point $pt_+$, one can prove that we get a $(2,1,0)$ TQFT. I
know how to verify this. However, this construction does not seem
natural to me. Thus I'd like to ask:

#### Question

1. Is this extension from $(2,1)$ to $(2,1,0)$ unique? Namely, is this the
   only way that extends the already defined $(2,1)$ theory?
2. If so, how
   would one argue? And also if this is the case, how can one go to
   higher codimension, if we have started from dimension 3 or higher?
3. Can
   one canonically get a fully extended $n$-TQFT from this procedure?

Comment: 1. The extension should definitely be unique because the whole theory can be computed from the value of the point.

Comment: 3. Dikkgraaf-Witten theory is fully extended in all dimensions, so the answer is yes

Comment: @DanielBarter The fact that the whole theory can be computed from the value of the point does not seem go guarantees uniqueness -- perhaps we can assign another category to $pt_+$ that still gives the same assignments to dimension $1$ and $2$ spaces.

Comment: Yes, this is true. For example, Rep(G) and Vec(G) define the same TQFT. If two categories are 2-Morita equivalent, they have the same associated TQFTs

Comment: What do you mean by Vec($G$) here? And what is true? Do you mean that "yes, the uniqueness is true up to 2-Morita equivalence"? Would you mind pointing out some reference for this? Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry, Vec(G) is the category of G-graded vector spaces. And yes, my claim is that if C and D are Morita equivalent fusion categories, then the corresponding Turaev-Viro TQFTs are equivalent. Unfortunately, I don't have a good reference. It is probably hidden somewhere in one of Kevin Walker's papers though. It is much easier to justify if you think about TQFT from a physicists perspective

Comment: No worries! I will dig into that. Thank you very much!